# How to allocate a desired address in Ram with malloc or other function?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was asked a question during an C Language interview. the question is:
 Can I change the address?

struct node * root;
root=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

printf("%d",root) =10128000  // new address:  root=101590000

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? You know that in modern environments all addresses are virtual?

Comment: Jesus Christ, of course not. It is possible in assembler but C is a higher level language, at least compared with assembler.

Comment: There are multiple layers between your program and physical memory. If you have an address in your program, ex. `0xaabbccdd` that doesn't mean that under this exact memory cell inside your hardware you will find your value. Such memory cell may not exists on your hardware.

Comment: Closest you can likely get is with `mmap()` and even that can be pretty iffy.

Comment: XY problem? Why are you asking this question?

Comment: Re "*Sorry, I'm beginner*", Definitely an [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341), then. Why do you think you need the block to be at a specific address? What are you actually trying to do? (Fix the question; don't add in the comments)

Comment: Your edit didn't address either of my questions.

Comment: Please don't edit your question such that none of the orifinal question remains. If you need to ask a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

None of the C standard library's allocation functions allow you to specify the address where you want the allocated space to be.  It would not make sense to do so, because it's very unlikely for the programmer to know or care what specific address they get, unless something known to them is already there, in which case it's not an available address.

You can, however, allocate a large block (*e.g.* via `malloc`), and then manually assign chunks of that block however you like.  That allows you to choose your own addresses relative to the base of the allocated block.  For example:

```
my_node *node_base = malloc(AS_MUCH_MEMORY_AS_I_NEED);

// ...

// malloc analog:
size_t an_index = choose_a_node_index_by_some_criteria();
my_node *node = node_base + an_index;

// free analog:
mark_index_available_again(an_index);
```

Of course, the devil is in the details, and those are both specific to your needs and more complex than I'm prepared to go into here.  Overall, this is not something that a self-declared beginner really ought to be trying to do.

Comment: Note that POSIX `mmap()` does allow specification of a desired address.

Comment: @AndrewHenle but this would be a hint anyway. Otherwise `MAP_FIXED` is required which seems to be non-POSIX. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: Thank you for answer ."That allows you to choose your own addresses relative to the base of the allocated block."  Can you get a code sample for this sentence?

Comment: Yes, @AndrewHenle, but `mmap()` is not part of the C standard library, and it is not guaranteed to successfully map to the specified address.

Comment: Ok, @hgaukrabnu, I added a sketch of an example, but really the take home should be: "don't attempt this until you know what you're doing, and why."